# RingtoneManager cannot access some methods

Tags: android, ringtonemanager

`RingtoneManager` has this public method `addCustomExternalRingtone`. But i cant access this method from my code. Why? This method is public.

Comment: It's marked `@hide`, which means it's not available in the SDK: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/RingtoneManager.java#875.

Comment: its not marked with @hide. https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-28/blob/809dd8b7822332cdbc68939d777eb70a6951908a/android/media/RingtoneManager.java

Comment: Yes, it is: https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-28/blob/809dd8b7822332cdbc68939d777eb70a6951908a/android/media/RingtoneManager.java#L932.

Comment: u are correct. How do i access that  method? Just copy?

Comment: You _might_ be able to copy it out, but I see a few helper methods from utility classes that you'd have to copy, too. I can't guarantee that'll work, as I only gave it a glance. If that doesn't work, you could use reflection, but you have to jump through some extra hoops on Pie and above, due to non-SDK interface restrictions introduced then, and strengthened since.